# Exception when registering service and Broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, instantiation, runtimeexception

I have two classes

1)public class MainActivity extends Service { 
2)public class Boot extends BroadcastReceiver {

How can i register these in Manifestfile.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

when MainActivity is registered like this it shows an exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sim/com.example.sim.MainActivity}:
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.sim.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Please help me to overcome this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MainActivity file you are extending Service and not Activity. So, in you manifest file, you don't have to use the tag `<Activity` ,instead use the tag `<service`.